# Clover credit card payment

Tags: c#, clover-payment

I am trying to integrate clover credit card payment in my website, I have created an order successfully and also got payment key for card encryption. But I need access token to make a payment with clover.

Where can i get it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, https://www.clover.com/

Comment: Why should i generate an app? I don't want to publish any app to clover. I just want to integrate payment in my site using clover.